# Disable the parent view when subview opened

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have two views. viewController and myCustomAlert. i have added myCustomAlert as a subview in viewController.

this is the function which is called when myCustomAlert is added as a subview.

```
-(void)ratingAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myCustomAlert" owner:self options:nil
        ];

        Custom_view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 287, 165);

        [self.view addSubview:Custom_view];
         self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false;
         Custom_view.userInteractionEnabled = true;

    }
}
```

i want parent view to be disabled so i disable the userinteraction but it disable the subview too. how to do that?? i want my subview to work like an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can try is set subviews frame in a way that it completely hides its super view controller i.e. 0,0,320,460 and make sure that the content on subviews are properly placed at position where you want, and then make the background color of subview transparent.

myCustomAlert.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 0):

when you add a subview to a specific view, the subview and parent become one view collectively, i.e. the parent view. so disabling interaction will disable both.

for you is to present modelview controller with animated property as false and disable parent view interaction. tell me if you achieve your goal

Comment: myCustomAlert is only a nib file. it doesn't have .h or .m file.

Comment: make a new viewcontroller class then